# Qt prevent controls moving when window resized

Tags: c++, qt, layout, resize

I have a Qt application which has a window based on a `QWdiget`.  Inside my window I have two `QVBoxLayout`s and one `QHBoxLayout` with controls underneath the first two Vertical layouts.  When my window is resized, the `QVBoxLayout` move apart and the `QHBoxLayout` underneath also moves away.  I want to prevent this from happening, what is the best way to do this?

All these layouts are inside a `QGridLayout`.

Comment: Did you look at the Layout Management documentation ?  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/layout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a window's layout like this :
[image: windows layout]

The layouts is going to resize depending on the size of the objects in them. To solve your problem, you should set the alignment of your layouts within the grid layout using [setAlignment](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qlayout.html#setAlignment) method.

by the way, if nothing works, you can always [write your own layout manager](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html#id-76646bf7-3857-41c6-b9fe-8bbe04ac06cf).